# Trying to setup gitea server: Issue with nginx config (I think) - "git.domain.com" displays main page i.e. "domain.com"

Tags: reactjs, nginx, digital-ocean, certbot, gitea

I'm using DigitalOcean droplet to host React app, which is just a personal website of mine. It works fine. I also used certbot to get a ssl certificate on my page.

Now I'm trying to run gitea server under a subdomain. So I did the setup, got to the initial install page (git.domain.com/install), and finished that. I logged into my running gitea server and everything seemed to be working fine.

Then I extended my ssl certification to include the subdomain. It sill seemed to be working fine from what I could tell.

However, now (5 hours later), when I try to go to "git.domain.com" it displays my personal web page, instead of the gitea page. But the url remains the same i.e. "git.domain.com". (So, maybe it was broke after I the added the ssl cert to the subdomain, but didn't realize the problem, because of the browser cache history)

I checked...

- gitea is still running under localhost:3000
- Nginx is running without error
- sites-available is linked with sites-enabled
- DNS records on DigitalOcean

I assume the issue is either with ...

- nginx config files
- ssl cert config with gitea (I used certbot to extend the existing ssl cert to include the subdomain)
- gitea app.ini config

It's driving me a little mad that I can't figure it out, so I decided to post this. **Any help is appreciated. Let me know, if there is any other pertinent information I should provide.**

Here are the files:

```
# nginx domain.com file

server {

        root /var/www/domain.com/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

```
# nginx git.domain.com file

server {
        server_name git.domain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;

        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = git.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name git.domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

```
# gitea app.ini file

APP_NAME = Gitea - Git with a cup of tea
RUN_USER = git
RUN_MODE = prod

[oauth2]
JWT_SECRET = FakePass

[security]
INTERNAL_TOKEN = FakeToken
INSTALL_LOCK   = true
SECRET_KEY     = FakeSecretKey

[database]
DB_TYPE  = mysql
HOST     = 127.0.0.1:3306
NAME     = gitea
USER     = gitea
PASSWD   = FakePassword
SSL_MODE = disable
CHARSET  = utf8
PATH     = /var/lib/gitea/data/gitea.db
ROOT = /home/git/gitea-repositories

[server]
SSH_DOMAIN       = git.domain.com
DOMAIN           = git.domain.com
ROOT_URL         = http://localhost:3000/
DISABLE_SSH      = false
SSH_PORT         = 22
LFS_START_SERVER = true
LFS_CONTENT_PATH = /var/lib/gitea/data/lfs
LFS_JWT_SECRET   = FakeSecretJWTpassword 
OFFLINE_MODE     = false
HTTP_ADDR        = /run/gitea/gitea.sock
PROTOCOL         = unix
UNIX_SOCKET_PERMISSION = 666

[mailer]
ENABLED = false

[service]
REGISTER_EMAIL_CONFIRM            = false
ENABLE_NOTIFY_MAIL                = false
DISABLE_REGISTRATION              = true
ALLOW_ONLY_EXTERNAL_REGISTRATION  = false
ENABLE_CAPTCHA                    = false
REQUIRE_SIGNIN_VIEW               = false
DEFAULT_KEEP_EMAIL_PRIVATE        = false
DEFAULT_ALLOW_CREATE_ORGANIZATION = true
DEFAULT_ENABLE_TIMETRACKING       = true
NO_REPLY_ADDRESS                  = noreply.localhost

[picture]
DISABLE_GRAVATAR        = false
ENABLE_FEDERATED_AVATAR = true

[openid]
ENABLE_OPENID_SIGNIN = true
ENABLE_OPENID_SIGNUP = false

[session]
PROVIDER = file

[log]
MODE      = file
LEVEL     = info
ROOT_PATH = /var/lib/gitea/log
```